Deploy to Cloud run spends 4 minutes on "Analyzing workspace for builders..."
I'm using Version 2.19.0 of the Cloud Code for Visual Studio Code Extension. My development system OS is Windows 11.
I have not changed any extension settings, they are all at their original defaults.
The extension works great in that it publishes my project to Google Cloud Run and everything works.
My only issue is that it spends 4 minutes before it actually starts publishing "Analyzing workspace for builders". The Output pane shows "Retrieving builders." during this time. Once it finishes the output shows the following items:
Getting Gcloud Login State.
Using current GCP Project "redacted-10101"
Checking Cloud Run API status.
Getting Cloud Run Services for project "redacted-10101".
The deploy pane then shows the GCP Project, Service Settings, Revision Settings and so on.
From there I click the Deploy button to continue.
I've tried Cloud Build vs Local with no affect.
Gemini suggested I add a .dockerignore and a .gcloudignore file to keep it from searching through unnecessary folders. I added those files and put all the usual .git bin/ obj/ folders in. These changes had no measurable affect.
Interestingly, nothing seems to affect the timing, it's almost exactly 4 minutes each time which makes me wonder if there is some kind of timeout that is being run out.
What is the "builder" that it's looking for and is there some way to identify precisely where to look for that builder?

In the Cloud Run Console, there is the output of the Skaffold command that is run during deploy, if you copy that command and append args -v trace, then running that locally will provide some additional details that can provide some insight into where that time is being spent.
If you attach that output here, it may be easier to identify where the bottleneck exists.
